# Group pair of elements in a List

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, rdd, breadth-first-search

I have a list (in Scala).

```
val seqRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a","b"),("b","c"),("c","a"),("d","b"),("e","c"),("f","b"),("g","a"),("h","g"),("i","e"),("j","m"),("k","b"),("l","m"),("m","j")))
```

I group by the second element for a particular statistics and flatten the result into one list.

```
val checkItOut = seqRDD.groupBy(each => (each._2))
                   .map(each => each._2.toList)
                   .collect
                   .flatten
                   .toList
```

The output looks like this:

```
checkItOut: List[(String, String)] = List((c,a), (g,a), (a,b), (d,b), (f,b), (k,b), (m,j), (b,c), (e,c), (i,e), (j,m), (l,m), (h,g))
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is "group" all elements (not pairs) that are connected to other elements in any pair to one list.
For example:
c is with a in one pair, a is with g in its next, so (a,c,g) are connected. Then, c is also with b and e, that b is with a, d, f, k and these are with other characters in some other pair. I want to have them in a list.

I know this can be done with a BFS traversal. BUt wondering if there was an API in Spark that does this?

Comment: You're looking for GraphX, connectedComponents:

Comment: You can do this with `groupWith` - something I wrote for another question.  It adds elements to a group if the predicate matches for any existing member of that group, which is what you need here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35919875/21755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphX, Connected Components: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#connected-components

Comment: Had never heard of this Spark library! I really think Spark API set needs a better organizing.